# Oracle ADF: Panel group layout background image is not getting displayed in browser in bounded task-flow

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing a web application using ADF (JDeveloper 11.1.2.4). I have created a template in that I have panelGroupLayout. For this grouplayout I have set a background image, and created a test.jsf page from this template.
When I am running this page directly, the background image is getting displayed in the browser. I have placed this page in a bounded taskflow.
My problem is when I running this page from a bounded taskflow the background image is not getting displayed.

Image is getting displayed for this URL:
[non-promising local IPv4 URL "login"](http://127.0.0.1:7101/EasyRUN-ViewController-context-root/faces/login?_adf.ctrl-state=1px1s1o6o_26)

Image is not getting displayed for this URL:
[non-promising local IPv4 URL "admin-flow-definition"](http://127.0.0.1:7101/EasyRUN-ViewController-context-root/faces/admin-flow-definition/homePage?_adf.ctrl-state=1px1s1o6o_29)

My code:

```
<f:facet name="top">
    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pt_pgl1" layout="horizontal" valign="top">
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pt_pgl20">
            <af:image source="#{resource['images:EasyRUN_Banner_1Part.png']}" shortDesc="EasyRUN Banner "
                      id="pt_i1"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pt_pgl21" layout="horizontal"
                             inlineStyle='background-image:url("ERUnBPart2.png");'>
            <af:spacer width="37" height="103" id="pt_s45"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pt_pgl19" layout="vertical"
                             inlineStyle='background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image:url("ERUnBPart2.png");'
                             halign="left">
            <af:spacer width="145" height="20" id="pt_s42"/>
            <af:outputText value="#{attrs.user}" id="pt_ot1"/>
            <af:spacer width="10" height="20" id="pt_s43"/>
            <af:commandLink text="Logout" id="pt_cl1"/>
            <af:spacer width="100" height="35" id="pt_s44"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
</f:facet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your images are not under WEB-INF folder, but somewhere under public_html folder.

If your image is under a folder structure like:

```
MyApplication/MyViewController/public_html/images
```

Your page can reference this way:

```
<af:commandMenuItem [..] icon="../images/GlobalSearch/key.gif"/>
```

Comment: Thank for you time Florin. My image is under D:\Oracle ADF Projects\EasyRUN\ViewController\public_html

Comment: how do you reference the image from the page? Can you show that code?

Comment: Ya sure. I have pasted my code in the question as edit.

Comment: and my image is under /viewcontroller/webcontent in jdeveloper.

Comment: Okay for commandMenuItem i will use the above pattern to set the image. But I need to set panelGrouplayout background . So I followed you suggession #{resource['images:ERUN_Banner2.png']}. Code inlineStyle='background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image:#{resource[&apos;images:ERUN_Banner2.png&apos;]};' it is showing some error

Comment: Thank you florin it is working .... I tried with this url("../ERUnBPart2.png")... It is working